# Converter dólares em real com Python

Tags: python

Criar um programa que pede a quantidade de US$ e a taxa e exibe a quantidade de R$.

```
dolar = float(input("Informe a quantidade de dólar para conversão: US$ "))
contaçao = float(input ("Informe o valor da cotação do dólar: R$ "))
conversao = float(input(("A quantidade de dólar convertido em real é: R$ ",conversao))
print (dolar*contacao)
```

Preciso fazer em Python.

Comment: oque ta dando errado aqui

Comment: Qual foi a mensagem de erro? O que você entendeu quando leu tal mensagem?

Comment: Que tal usar uma nomenclatura padronizada? `contacao` e `contaçao` são palavras distintas. Você deveria usar apenas um nome para se referir ao valor da cotação do dólar

Comment: Qual sua intenção na linha em que faz a leitura da variável `conversao`? Achei confuso você usar um comando de leitura para escrever a suposta resposta da conversão de dólares em reais

Answer (score 0):

Reescrevendo seu código de acordo uma lógica viável, ficaria desta forma. A cotação do `dolar` U$ seria o valor atual multiplicado pela cotação em R$. Basicamente isso seria atribuído a `conversao`. Veja:

```
dolar = float(input("Informe a quantidade de dólar para conversão: US$ "))
cotacao = float(input ("Informe o valor da cotação do dólar: R$ "))
conversao = dolar*cotacao
print('A quantidade de dólar convertido em real é: R$',conversao)
```

Para limitar a quantidade de casas decimais, por exemplo em 3, basta usar `"%.3f" % valor`. Veja um exemplo:

```
print('A quantidade de dólar convertido em real é: R$',("%.3f" % conversao))
```

Veja [funcionando aqui no repl.it](https://repl.it/LRNu).